# Missing SELECT keyword when inserting in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, visual-studio-2010, odp.net

I am completely blind with this Error. I'm more of a Java man than an ASP one. So here is my code and my question :

Here is my code that produce the error :

```
protected void ButtonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // OracleConnection connect = new OracleConnection();
       // connect.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Absensi2.Properties.Settings.Setting"].ConnectionString;
       //// SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(getConnection());
        var sql = "insert into master_dosen('NIP','NAMA_DOSEN','KETERANGAN') values (:NIP, :NAMA_DOSEN, :KETERANGAN)";

        using (OracleConnection c = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Absensi2.Properties.Settings.Setting"].ConnectionString))
        {
            c.Open();
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, c))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(":NIP", TextBoxNIP.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(":NAMA_DOSEN", TextBoxNamaDosen.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(":KETERANGAN", TextBoxKeterangan.Text);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            c.Close();
        }
```

The error is :
ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
in line cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

[image: Missing SELECT]

I already search and it says deprecated. is it true?

NB : I am using ODP.NET, and I am using visual studio 2010.

Comment: column name should not be in single quote.

Comment: single quote is valid for my-sql only .. so remove single quote..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your query is that you are wrapping column names with single quotes which makes them string literal.

To fix the problem, just remove the single quotes around the column names:

```
var sql = "insert into master_dosen(NIP,NAMA_DOSEN,KETERANGAN) ...";
```

Comment: What the heck man, Seriously. oh my god i'm laugh with that solutions. Thanks Man you are the best and i'm the worst. It works flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void ButtonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // OracleConnection connect = new OracleConnection();
       // connect.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Absensi2.Properties.Settings.Setting"].ConnectionString;
       //// SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(getConnection());
        var sql = "insert into master_dosen(NIP,NAMA_DOSEN,KETERANGAN) values (:NIP, :NAMA_DOSEN, :KETERANGAN)";

        using (OracleConnection c = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Absensi2.Properties.Settings.Setting"].ConnectionString))
        {
            c.Open();
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, c))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(":NIP", TextBoxNIP.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(":NAMA_DOSEN", TextBoxNamaDosen.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(":KETERANGAN", TextBoxKeterangan.Text);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            c.Close();
        }
```

Try this it will work ,I think you miss the sql insert syntax

Comment: Yeah bro. I knew it, But the fastest man to answer got it first. Thanks man. I laugh with that. LoL